# jQuery and autocomplete to get from database

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am very new to ajax. The requirement is to autocomplete values from user table using ajax and JQuery. These is piece of code what I have taken from net.

With url, I am able to get JSON of user table. With this code I am just able to get plain drop down but values are not displayed.

But I can see the list of entities of user table in log files. With these two lines
     - Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction 
     - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher

Please help me out with this issue.

```
  /* The script what i have written */

  <script>

    $(function() {

        $("#clientadminid").autocomplete({
            source: "http://localhost:8080/articles.json",
            minLength: 2,
            dataType:"json",
            type:"Get",
            select: function(event, ui) {
                var url = ui.item.id;
                if(url != '#') {
                    location.href = '/blog/' + url;
                }
            },

           success: function (data) {

              response($.map(data.articles,function(item){
                return {
                value:item.username,
                lable:item.username

                    };

                })); 
                }
        });

    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Any errors? if not just type something in the search box and see, it will display after that only

Comment: no error, but nothing is returned

Comment: Can you create a code snippet of your code. It will be easier to debug

Comment: hi kuru, i was working on this, i changed code, with this code i am just able to get plain drop down. but no values are displayed.

Comment: i have added, label, now i am able to get list of entites in log files

Answer (score 0):

Add the label also in the response return. Label is used for display. Your code would look like:
    $(function() {

```
$("#clientadminid").autocomplete({
    source: "http://localhost:8080/articles.json",
    minLength: 2,
    dataType:"json",
    type:"Get",
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var url = ui.item.id;
        if(url != '#') {
            location.href = '/blog/' + url;
        }
    },

   success: function (data) {

      response($.map(data.articles,function(item){
        return {
        value:item.username,
        label:item.username
            };

        })); 
        }
});
```

});